# como sacar el año de un campo tipo fecha en spark

Tags: python, mysql, pyspark, apache-spark, spark

¿Qué semana del año 2018 tuvo el mayor número de llamadas?**

```
final_df.withColumn("IncidentDate",to_timestamp(col("IncidentDate"))).withColumn("year", date_format(col("IncidentDate"), "Year")).show()
```

> IllegalArgumentException: All week-based patterns are unsupported since Spark 3.0, detected: Y, Please use the SQL function EXTRACT instead

la funcion sql extract solo me permite sacar el año el mes o el dia de una fecha en concreto y necesito hacerlo para todas las fechas de mi data frame